# JQuery Uncaught Reference message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this function written:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getStartDate(value) {
    $.post("gSearch.php", {dateSearch:value}, function(data){
        $('#results').html(data);
    )};
   }                            
</script>
```

and this piece of HTML:

```
<input id="startdate" name="startdate" type="text" onkeyup="getStartDate(this.value)">
```

but I get this in my console in Chrome; can any one help me as to why?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getStartDate is not defined
> (anonymous function)gReport.php:172
> onkeyup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getStartDate(value) {
    $.post("gSearch.php", {dateSearch:value}, function(data){
        $('#results').html(data);
    });
   }                            
</script>
```

The brace was not closed properly, or was that a typo ?

Comment: This is likely the problem.  This is a syntax error which makes getStartDate() to not be defined.  A simple look at the error console or the console window in any debugger would show JS syntax errors.  That's the first place one should look when something isn't working.